# Check hard bounce email in rails using mandrill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mandrill

Is there any way to find whether the email is legitimate or not. I am using mandrill and some emails were hard bounced so, is there a way where mandrill can send a response to my rails application that email was hard bounced. Or is there any other way to find that email actually exists or not through other medium. I saw a gem https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier but there were some issues so I am not sure to use it or not.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Mandrill's [webhooks](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583217-Introduction-to-Webhooks)

The idea is that you set up an endpoint to receive event notifications (including bounces) from Mandrill.

Comment: thank for your response, but will I receive response as soon as it triggers the confirmation email as I need to inform user that the email you entered is wrong as I will be sending a response to mobile application and I do not want him/her to wait

Comment: The only way to know for sure that an email has bounced or not is to wait for event notifications.

Answer (score 1):

One best solution is to implement webhooks which returns all status of emails sent. The webhook can be customised to recieve what response you can recieve including sent and delivery also. It also helps in tracking open and click rates which could be later used for filtering privileged users.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/webhooks.html